# modifying BIT column to ENUM in mysql/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

**mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.6-MariaDB**

I have run into a problem executing an UPDATE statment in the O'Reilly book "Learning MySQL and MariaDB". The code is in chapter 5 - on pages 218 & 219 of the ebook I'm reading.

The field "endangered" in the table "birds_new" is of type bit(1).   The intent is to change it the type to ENUM.

```
alter table birds_new
modify column endangered
enum ('Extinct', 'Extinct in Wild', 'Threatened - Critically Endangered',
'Threatened - Endangered', 'Threatened - Vulnerable', 
'Lower Risk - Conservation Dependent', 'Lower Risk - Near Threatened',
'Lower Risk - Least Concern')
after family_id;
```

It fails: 
ERROR 1265 (01000): Data Truncated for column 'endangered' at row 1

The data type remains bit(1).
What is wrong with the ALTER statement?
Is it simply not possible to do this with an ALTER statment?
I have made the change with two separate ALTER statements: DROP COLUMN, then ADD COLUMN.

Comment: I would not use enum for this field at all, since this list is likely to change - which is a pain in the a** in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

`BIT(1)` and `ENUM` are somewhat different.  I suggest you do it in multiple steps.  But first, I suggest your `ENUM` be `NOT NULL` and have and extra, first option of `unknown` (or some such).  Don't you also need 'Not endangered'?

```
ALTER TABLE birds_new
    CHANGE COLUMN endangered old_end BIT(1) ...,
    ADD COLUMN endangered ENUM 
           ('unknown, 'Extinct', ..., 'Not endangered') NOT NULL;

UPDATE birds_new
    SET endangered = IF(old_end, 'unknown', 'Not endangered')

ALTER TABLE birds_new
    DROP COLUMN old_end;
```

You will then need some code to turn `'unknown'` into the specific level of "endangered".